# Is there a way to let Eclipse CDT have a default or shared linker flag entry for all projects?

Tags: eclipse, linker, settings

Basically, I want to be able to add "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" to the linker flag for all projects I will be making.
I can do this manually for each project I start with, but shouldn't there be an easier and more efficient way to share this linker flag with new projects (they need not be existing ones)?

Dev-C++ has linker flag settings shared by all projects as far as I know (same settings for the linker). I can forego this if Eclipse had a way to show the output of a running program in its "Console" pane (but I accept that this is a separate problem). The linker flags above make this possible, so yeah.

Thanks in advance.